# pow() from math.h library - How to Apply using functions

Tags: c++, pow, math.h

So I'm writing a bit of code that needs to raise a function's return value to a certain power. I recently discovered that using the '^' operator for exponentiation is useless because in C++ it is actually an XOR operator or something like that. Now here's the code I want to write:

```
int answer = pow(base, raisingTo(power));
```

Now can anyone tell me if this is right? I'll explain the code. I've declared an int variable answer as you all are aware of, and initialized it to the value of any variable called 'base', raised to the return value of the raisingTo() function acting on any other variable called 'power'. When I do this (and I edit & compile my code in Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition), a red dash appears under the word 'pow' and an error appears saying: "more than one instance of overloaded function 'pow' matches the argument list"
Can someone please solve this problem for me? And could you guys also explain to me how this whole pow() function actually works, cos frankly www.cplusplus.com references are a little confusing as I am still only a beginner!

Comment: I'm not a beginner in computer programming, I'm only a beginner in C++. Thanks, Joey.

Comment: @Joey  No way.  it forces good programming skills.

Comment: @RamSidharth As an aside, the way your code is written above, you will be losing precision; in other the number returned from pow() will be truncated, which is fine if thats what you want.  Also, I find the Visual Studio does too much work and gets in the way when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze.aspx) states it pretty explicitly already:

> The `pow(int, int)` overload is no longer available. If you use this overload, the compiler may emit C2668 **[EDIT: That's the error you get]**. To avoid this problem, cast the first parameter to double, float, or long double.

Also, to calculate *base*<sup>*power*</sup> you just write

```
pow(base, power)
```

And with above hint:

```
int result = (int) pow((double)base, power);
```

Comment: @Joey Would casting the return of pow() be necessary, normally C++ would just truncate the value going into "answer."  Or is this VS getting in the way?

Comment: Mike D: No idea. I think in C you'd have to cast. I have no clue whether it's necessary in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The pow() function returns either a `double` or a `float`, so the first step would be to change `answer` to one of those.  Second, what is `raisingTo()` returning.  Unless your are doing something that's not evident, you don't need that, but it should still work.  Also, both arguments should be `doubles`, according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/).